# BEFORE DELETE: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, linked-list, triggers

I am trying to implement a playlist editor that allows changing the track order.
For this I was thinking of a linked-list-approach. My current issue is that I would like to update the playlist when a track is removed from the middle so that the "chain" is restored. e.g. if my tracks are `A->B->C` and i delete `B`, I would like a trigger to update the table so that the final result is `A->C`.

My DBMS is MySQL and my current table schema and trigger attempt are as follows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE playlist_track
(
    id int(11) auto_increment,
    playlist_id int(11),
    track_id int(11),
    next_playlist_track_id int(11) null /* the successor track on the playlist */
);
```

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER relink_playlist
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON playlist_track FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE playlist_track
SET next_playlist_track_id = old.next_playlist_track_id
WHERE next_playlist_track_id = old.id;
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, i get the error `Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.` when trying to delete a row now.
Can this be done using MySQL triggers or will i have to implement it in my app logic?

Comment: make a transaction update then delete finally commit

Comment: Your scheme seems to be errorneous. The parent-child relation does not match. The track cannot depend on another track. The tracks ordering in the playlist is an attribute of this playlist. So the tracks ordering must be stored within the playlist attributes. Think about JSON array, it seems that this form of track ordering storage is close to the ideal for these purposes.